# Wordpress plugin url for form submit

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, routing

I am creating a custom plugin that has dynamic forms and I wanted to ask on how I can create a dynamic form action url.

Example is Contact Form 7, how did cf7 create the form action url without creating a new page or a file for submission?

Please share any idea on how to do something like that for plugin.

Thanks

Comment: ah okay, i got an idea from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694563/wordpress-plug-ins-how-to-add-custom-url-handles

Comment: You could go into cf7 and tear it apart, break it to find out how it does what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't need a new submit URL, most of the plugins submit the form on the same page(the one on which the form was rendered), then before rendering the form they check if there is submitted data present. Then for eg. if data is present then they have to show a thankyou message & skip rendering the form, if there is no data present they will just render the form

This logic of course differs a lot